# Delete windows themes with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, themes, unauthorized

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to delete all of the .theme files in C:\Windows\Resources\Themes on a running system. I use Unrestricted execution policy, tried to take own with takeown.exe and set-acl for the currently running user, but still i get error  permission denied - unauthorized access.
Is it possible to delete those files without using any community extension scripts?

My currently working script without set-acl - which I want to use instead of takeown and icacls executables:

```
takeown /f C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\ /R
icacls C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\ /grant administrators:F /T

Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\architecture.theme
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\characters.theme
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\landscapes.theme
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\nature.theme
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\scenes.theme
```

Comment: Exact errors and the script would help. Have you tried in SYSTEM context via `psexec`?

Comment: Are you running Powershell as an administrator? The execution policy really only controls your ability to run scripts, it won't give you new permissions or access.

You could try right clicking on Powershell or CMD and selecting "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Yes, I always run as administrator.

Comment: I am look for the same solution as this script:

Comment: If you can edit your question to include your script we will be able to help you more.

Comment: Still suggest using SYSTEM context via psexec

Comment: This script is executed from Task Sequence - it is using SYSTEM context by default, just like psexec.